# Why is ls -i slower than ls?

Tags: ls, directory-structure, inode

I know that **ls** lists the names of the files in a given directory and **ls -i** shows the names and the inode numbers.

But why is it slower?

**EDIT**: This happens with big directories

The names and the inode numbers are stored in the directory information block together, hence why does it take more time to query the inode numbers?

Comment: All the information is not lumped together, and you are not telling us how big is your directory. I suspect you are dealing with a very *big* directory, slow machine/VM lacking on RAM maybe? If you add more data to your questions, you may get more interesting answers.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, the file names and inode numbers are together in the directory contents, they kinda need to be since the point of a directory is to tell the inode number corresponding to a name... Also, of course it only happens on big directories: on small ones nobody would notice!

Comment: @ilkkachu Yeah, I know, but the inodes are not...late night comment.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, the difference between `ls` and `ls -i` is just that the latter prints the inode _numbers_ too, it shouldn't need the contents of the inodes any more than plain `ls` does or doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strace` shows me that `ls -i` is calling `lstat()` on each filename

That would explain the extra work.

Given that readdir() has already returned the inode number this appears to be sub-optimal

while this feels like a bug, this behaviour is for consistency with mount points. (see Thomas' comment)

Comment: I thnk it is a feature, not a bug

Comment: Actually it seems to be the bug fix: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commit;h=a977dbbe78f4dcb64e008f41c8a46c4972af834b

Comment: Good detective work!